# Is stackblitz's terminal using the host or external processing power?

Tags: stackblitz, web-container

**In other words** : is it some kind of containerization/ VM technology or it's just my computer doing the whole thing ? and where's the downloaded data stored ?

#### Things I tried :

Code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-hiwmkj?file=index.js) , uncomment and use `node index.js` to run

##### 1- Checking system info using `systeminformation` gives: (obviously not my specs)

> manufacturer: 'Intel',
>
> brand: 'Core™ i9-9880H',

other information weren't very useful at least for my level of experience .

##### 2- Testing network interfaces

> iface: 'en0',
>
> ifaceName: 'en0',
>
> default: false,
>
> ip4: '192.168.1.104',

I checked my host's local ip using `ifconfig`  , **not the same**.

##### 3- Checking external ip / Network speed

Wasn't able to do that , I guess only connections to npm server are allowed for downloading packages , fetching other webpages or connecting to speed-test servers isn't working .

So far it seemed like it's not My computer **BUT** then I tried running `npm i largest-package` and directly cut my PC's connectivity (the command should continue running on the server and I should find the package installed when I reconnect) this ,however , **did not** happen .

#### As for the Data

I checked the cached data in browser.. very small (in my humble opinion)
[image: Stackbliz data]

#### Finally

Checking the documentation
[image: search]

yields (09/03/2022) [link](https://developer.stackblitz.com/docs/platform/#curious-how-our-technology-works)
[image: not found]

I'd appreciate you helping me wrap my head around this .